# Why I am getting {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type",

Tags: api, razor

I am trying to post a form in razor page ?

```html
<form method="post" asp-controller="Emp" asp-action="Edit" action="https://localhost:7257/api/Emp/Edit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">id</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Enter id">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Mobile</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
</form>
```

I am getting `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type",`

```
  public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] dynamic obj)
        {
            string serializedObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
            var dtoModel = new DTO.Employee();
            dtoModel = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DTO.Employee>(serializedObject);
            var entity = unitOfWork.Employee.Get(int.Parse(dtoModel.EmployeeId));
            unitOfWork.Clear();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.FirstName= dtoModel.FirstName;
                entity.LastName= dtoModel.LastName;
                entity.Email= dtoModel.Email;
                entity.Bank = new Entity.EmployeeBank();
                entity.Bank.EmployeeId = dtoModel.EmployeeId;
                entity.Bank.Iban = "";
                entity.Bank.IsActive = false;
                entity.Bank.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.DeleteUserID = -1;
                entity.Bank.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.CreationUserID = -1;
                entity.Bank.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.IsDeleted = false;
                entity.Bank.DeletedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.Bank.Name = "";
                entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                entity.ModifyUserID = 2;
                unitOfWork.Employee.Update(entity);
                unitOfWork.Complete();
                unitOfWork.Clear();
                return Ok(dtoModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "ID is not valid"
                }
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems you are using ASP.Net Core with Razor pages. Maybe you should add relevant tags and also add necessary code from where this error is returned.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes I am calling web api from razor pages

Comment: The error message and code doesn't match. Where do you get this error?

Comment: @kiner_shah I get the error message in  public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] dynamic obj) action

Comment: FromForm fixed it but no values